# Accessing objects inside arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, javascript-objects

My API is returning the below response. I am trying to filter through the links to check if the source and target name properties in each object match a specific string. Any idea how I can do this, I am have troubling getting to the name property.

Currently this.chart.links.target.name and this.chart.links.source.name are returning undefined. I cannot seem to access the name properties.

```
    Proxy {nodes: Array(69), links: Array(68)}
    [[Handler]]: Object
    [[Target]]: Object
    links: Array(68)
    0:
    circular: false
    index: 0
    real_value: 10
    source: {name: 'String1', color: 'yellow', index: 30, sourceLinks: Array(30), targetLinks: Array(24), …}
    target: {name: 'String2', color: 'red', index: 0, sourceLinks: Array(0), targetLinks: Array(1), …}
    value: 10
    width: 2.152297042164877
    y0: 111.36731918963686
    y1: 193.80113278791737
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    1: {source: {…}, target: {…}, value: 10, real_value: 10, index: 1, …}
    2: {source: {…}, target: {…}, value: 10, real_value: 10, index: 2, …}
    3: {source: {…}, target: {…}, value: 10, real_value: 10, index: 3, …}
    4: {source: {…}, target: {…}, value: 10, real_value: 10, index: 4, …}
    5: {source: {…}, target: {…}, value: 10, real_value: 10, index: 5, …}
    6: {source: {…}, target: {…}, value: 10, real_value: 10, index: 6, …}
    7: {source: {…}, target: {…}, value: 10, real_value: 10, index: 7, …}
```

this is how my filter is looking:

```
const dataToFilter = ['String1', 'String2']

    const links = this.chart.links.filter(io => 
          !dataToFilter.includes(io.source.name || io.target.name)
        )
```

Comment: Probably instead of `!dataToFilter.includes(io.source.name || io.target.name)` you want something along `!(dataToFilter.includes(io.source.name) || dataToFilter.includes(io.target.name))` to check against the names separately.

Comment: What's your question actually and whats inside the links object, you are not so clear

Comment: Sorry I edited it. Currently this.chart.links.target.name and this.chart.links.source.name are returning undefined. I cannot seem to access the name properties.

Comment: Actually if you want to include with the array you could do, if you do this.chart.links[0].target.name, you might get the value:

const links = this.chart.links.filter(io => 
          dataToFilter.includes(io.source.name) ||  dataToFilter.includes(io.source.name)
        )

Comment: Let's get one thing out of the way:  are you certain the data exists when you're trying to access it?  It's _very_ common for people to ask this question and turn out to be checking for the output of an asynchronous API call before the call is complete.  If you're not sure, do a `console.log(this.chart)` before your filter; make sure the result isn't `undefined`.

Comment: Yes what I posted above is the result of this.chart

Comment: I will try this anuj !

Comment: If I do this.chart.links[0].target.name it only returns the data for the first object in the array

Comment: Ok, I moved it as an answer.

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen can you tell me why it works vs when I did it the other way

Comment: @perrotss It has to do with the way [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) has been defined. It's checking against one value by definition. I think going with [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) would be another option in this case and you could consider rewriting to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `!dataToFilter.includes(io.source.name || io.target.name)` you want to have `!(dataToFilter.includes(io.source.name) || dataToFilter.includes(io.target.name))` to check against the names separately.